# Customising the NamePicker in Extension Library

Tags: xpages

I want to pick multiple customers from a view using the NamePicker in Extension Library.

```
<xe:namePicker id="namePicker1" for="customers">
  <xe:this.dataProvider>
    <xe:dominoViewNamePicker
       labelColumn="IdName" viewName="viewCustomers">
    </xe:dominoViewNamePicker>
  </xe:this.dataProvider>
</xe:namePicker>
```

The view has two columns:
1. CustId - customer id
2. IdName - customer id + “-“ + customer name

The NamePicker shows the IdName in the left box and the CustId for the selected customers in the right box.

Is it possible to change what the NamePicker shows in the right box?
I want to display the customer’s name in addition to CustId for the selected customers.

Is it possible to customise the Search function? It seems to me that now you can only search for something that match the beginning of the first column in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely. The great thing about the extension library (Extlib) is that it is open source. However, if you were looking for the quick solution of "Yeah, just set this property and you're done" ... well ... I'm afraid its not that easy. You can however, write your own component extending the component from the Extlib, and then add/override the functionality that you want to customize.

So to sum up, yes, its possible, but its not just as easy as changing some properties on the control.

Comment: Thank you. I thought I first had to check if there was a simple and smart way to solve the problem, like changing some properties. Now that I know there is no such way, I can begin digging into the open source ... Exciting!